how to shift a 440 Hz music file to 432 Hz?
Is it possible to use Audacity (or another software) to convert an audio file (music) so that the A note, typically tuned to 440 Hz, is shifted to 432 Hz?

Do you care about the tempo/length of the result?  (The simplest and highest-quality method would slow down and stretch the file by nearly 2%; there are more sophisticated methods that preserve the tempo and length, but they're likely to need more care and/or give worse quality.)

It's unclear what you're asking here. There are many questions and answers on here already about pitch shifting in Audacity and frequency shifting/time-stretching in general. You need to be more clear about what you want, please, and make sure it hasn't already been asked. Thanks :)

simple so: How can I shift the pitch of a piece of music so that the A 440 Hz note is tuned to 432 Hz, with the remaining notes adjusted accordingly? Time stretching is not an issue. I'm asking this because of claims that 432 Hz is a healing frequency, and I’d like to convert any music to this tuning.

Yes.
Audacity has function to change pitch. It is under menu Effect > Pitch and tempo.
